# How to hide 'Recently modified'

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, css, style

I have used the following as suggested in another post. and it seems to work, however when I save changes and reload page the 'recently modified' section comes back.

Am I missing something or is there something else I can try?

Thank you.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #s4-leftpanel {
        display: none
    }
    .s4-ca {
        margin-left: 0px
    }
</style>
<style type="text/css">
    .s4-recentchanges {
        display:none
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Where you have added this code? Are you using any webpart or created any custom solution?

Answer (score 0):

I added your code into my Site Pages library AllPages.aspx, it could work well.

The result is:
[image]

Which page did you add? Please make sure you are accessing the correct page which has been added the code.

In addition, if you just want to hide "Recently Modified" section, you can use the following code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .s4-recentchanges {
        display:none
    }
</style>
```

The result is:
[image]